# Consider the function $f : N \to R$ given by $f(n) = \frac{n^2}{7}$. Prove that the image of $f$ is countably infinite.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, infinity

Consider the function $f : N \to R$ given by $f(n) = \frac{n^2}{7}$. Prove that the image of $f$ is countably infinite.

I have no idea how to do this so can someone please show me ?

I know I can prove $2 \mathbb Z$ (even integers) is countably infinite by the bijection $g: \mathbb Z \to 2 \mathbb Z$ by $g(n)=2n$. Could I use a similar approach. So let $h:\mathbb N \to \frac{n^2}{7}$ by $h(n) =  \frac{n^2}{7}$?

Comment: Hint.Think about how far that function is from injective.

Comment: @EthanBolker It is injective ?

Comment: The image is infinite because it's unbounded (or because the domain is infinite and $f$ is injective), and it's countable because the domain is countable.

Comment: @Karl And so that means $f$ is countably infinite. Is this a standard method of proving questions of this type ?

Comment: Yeah, the statements in my comment can be proved in general (they're obvious once you're comfortable with the topic but you should definitely prove them for yourself) and then just applied in specific cases.

Comment: That way, you don't have to repeat much of the same proof work for different sets if they're countable for the same basic reason.

Comment: @NikitaMazepin No, it's not injective. But if you think about how it's not you can see why the image is infinite, hence countable.

Comment: @EthanBolker It is injective when the domain is the natural numbers is it not. What values prove otherwise ? Is Kar'l statement fine for the solution ?